# How to append td element in the same column of th element in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to append data to a table dynamically from  a JSON object.
After adding the titles as th elements, I am finding it difficult to add tr elements in the same column as the corresponding th element. Please help me.

```
{
"Category2":"Item2",
"Category1":"Item1",
"Category3":"Item3"
}

<table>
   <th>Category1</th>
   <th>Category2</th>
   <th>Category3</th>
</table>
```

Now, I need to add items in td tags in the columns same as their corresponding th elements. like:

```
        <table>
           <th>Category1</th>
           <th>Category2</th>
           <th>Category3</th>
           <tr>
           <td>Item1</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Item2</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>Item3</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
```

How can I do this using jQuery? (My problem is bigger than this. I simplified it so that it can be understood. Thank you!)

Comment: The format of your `<table>` is all wrong. What you need to do is put each set into its own `<row>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Effectively Build Table From JSON and Add It to DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734786/javascript-effectively-build-table-from-json-and-add-it-to-dom)

Comment: You need `tr` in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, Press `Run code snippet` and check if this works for you.

```js
var nodes = {
"Category2":"Item2",
"Category1":"Item1",
"Category3":"Item3"
};

$(function(){
    var th_elements = $('table').find('th'); // find <th> in HTML
    th_elements.each(function(){             // Loop as much <th> found
       var html = $.trim($(this).html());    // get HTML and compare with nodes key
       $('table').append('<td>'+nodes[html]+'</td>'); // append data to table
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
       <th>Category1</th>
       <th>Category2</th>
       <th>Category3</th>
 </table>
```